# Gradle - get the installation directory of a resolved java toolchain

Tags: java, gradle, toolchain

I have a gradle project which applies the following configuration:

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
        vendor = JvmVendorSpec.AMAZON
    }
}
```

In the same project I have a task responsible for compiling some C++ code, and that C++ code has a dependency on some JDK headers and libraries. I would like to acquire the installation directory (JAVA_HOME) of the resolved toolchain so I can provide that to the C++ compiler, ensuring the same JDK is used for compiling both the java components and the native components.

Is there any way to do this? I've looked at [JavaToolchainSpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/toolchain/JavaToolchainSpec.html) but it appears the specification isn't evaluated into a [JavaCompiler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/toolchain/JavaCompiler.html) until it's actually used inside specific tasks defined by the java plugin. Unfortunately the native compilation task which requires it is just a standard `exec` task.

I am using gradle version 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, you can find [how to get the JAVA_HOME](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#toolchains_for_tasks) in a task

```
def launcher = javaToolchains.launcherFor {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
}

tasks.named('anotherSampleTask') {
    javaHome = launcher.map { it.metadata.installationPath }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks. I didn't realise I'd be able to use `javaToolchains.compilerFor(spec)` from anywhere - I thought that would only be available within tasks from the java plugin

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the duplication of `JavaLanguageVersion.of(...)` from here and in the original code, if both code snippets are in the same build file? In my case, I'd like to get the exact version of the JDK that was provisioned,.